# Code works only sometimes for removing odd or even index items

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

Question :​ Write a Python program to remove the characters which have odd or even index
values of a given string.

1. I tried to make a copy of the list by deep copy .
2. I ran a loop from first list and checked for even then used pop method on second list to remove that specific index from the second list .

This code works for some inputs , I think mostly for those which doesn't have any repeated characters and doesn't work for others.

Code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import copy
list1 = input("Enter a string ")
list1 = list(list1)
list2 = copy.deepcopy(list1)
for i in list1:
    if list1.index(i)%2 != 0:
        list2.pop(list2.index(i))
print(list2)
```

The outputs for some samples are :

```
123456789 -> ['1', '3', '5', '7', '9'],   qwertyuiop -> ['q', 'e', 't', 'u', 'o'],   saurav -> ['s', 'u'],   11112222333344445555 -> ['1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '5', '5']
```

Comment: use `range()` it will be easy. You are iterating over values and again finding the indexes. you can simply use `range(1, len(list1), 2)`. with your approach If your list has duplicates it will always give first index only.

Comment: You shouldn't iterate over the characters but over the index numbers `0` to `len(list1)`. Because each deletion would shift the following indices the easiest way is to run backwards through the list from highest index to 0.

Comment: instead deleting from the list2 you can create empty list and append the even index values

Comment: Even index: `s=s[::2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation for `index`.  It returns the index of the first occurrence of the given value.  A simple `print` inside the loop will show you what's going on, in appropriate detail.  This is a basic debugging skill you need to learn for programming in any language.

```
import copy
list1 = input("Enter a string ")
list1 = list(list1)
list2 = copy.deepcopy(list1)
for i in list1:
    if list1.index(i)%2 != 0:
        print(i, list1.index(i), list2.index(i))
        list2.pop(list2.index(i))
        print(list2)
print(list2)
```

output:

```
Enter a string google
o 1 1
['g', 'o', 'g', 'l', 'e']
o 1 1
['g', 'g', 'l', 'e']
e 5 3
['g', 'g', 'l']
['g', 'g', 'l']
```

... and that's your trouble.  Fix your logic.  You already *know* the needed index to save or remove.  There is no need to extract the character, and then search for it again.  You already know where it is.

Even better, simply slice the original string for the characters you want:

```
print(list1[::2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `list.index` function. [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) states that it "returns zero-based index in the list of the first item whose value is equal to `x`." Because you are calling it on `list1` - and that is not modified - the result will always be `list1.index('a') == 1` for example.

The correct solution would be to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). A further problem exists here - because you are indexing from an array that you have not modified, you indexes will be off after the first `list.pop` operation. Every item after the one removed will have been shifted by 1. To correct this, you could instead try building a `list` instead of emptying one:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
list1 = input("Enter a string ")
list2 = []
for i, item in enumerate(list1):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        list2.append(item)
print(list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate at all. Just reference the string elements directly.

```
st="123456789"
print('Odd: ', list(st[::2]))
print('Even: ', list(st[1::2]))
```

Output:

```
Odd:  ['1', '3', '5', '7', '9']
Even:  ['2', '4', '6', '8']
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `list.index(i)` returns index in the list of the **first item** whose value is equal to `i`.

For example, `"saurav".index('a')` returns `1`. when you call `list2.pop(list2.index(i))` and you want to pop an `a`, it doesn't work well.

I think it can be simple using [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) as build-in function.

```py
list1 = list(input("Enter a string "))
list2 = list()
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        list2.append(list1[i])
print(list2)
```

It works with same way by following:

```py
list1 = list(input("Enter a string "))
list2 = list()
for i in range(0, len(list1), 2):
    list2.append(list1[i])
print(list2)
```

Also, you can use [Extended Slices](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) in Python 2.3 or above.

```py
list1 = list(input("Enter a string "))
list2 = list1[::2]
print(list2)
```